# break tag with justify-content-center in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make something like [this](https://www.sandboxww.com/). And able to place my text right in the middle of vertical and horizontal. But the break `<br>` tag is not working with this.

```
<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <h1 style="font-size:4vw;" class="display-3"><b>Some text</b></h1><br>
        <h1 style="font-size:5vw;" class="display-3">{{key_words}} !</h1><br>
        <h1 style="font-size:4vw;" class="display-3"><b>Some other texts</b></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's all coming in one line. And also how should I provide a styling with the `key_words` like the switching of `key_words` in animation ? I am trying to achieve this with bootstrap 4

Comment: They are coming in different lines. Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-rs473e?file=index.html)

Comment: @ranjeet8082 your example doesn't seem to take into account that this user is including Bootstrap.  The classes OP is using affect the display method of the child header elements.

Comment: Code snippet doesn't have bootstrap framework.

Comment: The `row`is flexbox and only meant to contain `col-*`.  Put the h1 in a col-12 instead.

Comment: Well Mr. Anonymous down voter, what do you say about the reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a **row**, use a **column** and you don't need the break tags at all

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container h-100">
  <div class="col h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <h1 style="font-size:4vw;" class="display-3"><b>Some text</b></h1>
    <h1 style="font-size:5vw;" class="display-3">{{key_words}} !</h1>
    <h1 style="font-size:4vw;" class="display-3"><b>Some other texts</b></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yea this one works but i am not sure how i am gonna give the animation